# Why The Elements of 2 Identical arrays Equal each other

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I should mention the purpose of this code is to tackle a leading zero scenario when finding date palindromes in dates in format MMDDYYY.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
unsigned numDigits (unsigned num)//this works
{
  if (num < 10) return 1;
  return 1+ numDigits(num/10);
}

int main ()
{
  unsigned date = 1111110;//01/11/1110(jan 11th of 1110 is palindrome)
  cout<<numDigits(date)<<"num of dig"<<endl;

  if (numDigits(date) == 7)
  { 
    unsigned array[8];
    unsigned number = date;
    unsigned revArr[8];

    for (int h = 7; h >= 0; h--) //this pops array withdate
    {
      array[h] = number % 10;
      number /= 10;
      cout<<array[h]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"vs"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //this pops revarray withdate
    {
    revArr[i] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    cout<<array[i]<<endl;
    }


    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
      if (array[j] == revArr[j])
      {
        cout<<j<<"th digit are" <<" equal"<<endl;
      }
    }

   }
  return 0;
}
```

In this case both of the arrays  are identical, I don't underdtdanwd why array[0] == revArr[0] but array[1] != revArr[1] and so on but array[7] == revArr[7] again... its boggling my mind.

Comment: You care mutating number with `number /= 10;`. Make a temp copy of number and use that in the loops

Comment: Thank you. yes adding a copy of variable "number"  and using it to populate the 'revArr[];' solves my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loops traverse all elements of the array. Even when the expression `number /= 10` is equal to `0`. In this case the zero is stored in the array elements because `0 / 10` gives again `0`.

Before the second loop write

```
number = date;
```